# AspNetCore в Docker контейнере, передача параметров запуска приложения

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docker, docker-compose, asp

Создал образ Docker используя Dockerfile.
В итоге получился образ с AspNetCore приложением.

в `Docker` контейнере крутится AspNetCore приложение,
которое стандартно настраивается с помощью `application.json` файла.

Получается при запуске приложения должно получить конфигурационные настройки,
например строку подключения к БД, режимы своей работы и т.д.

В отладке я запускаю `Docker` контейнер через `docker-compose.yml`
В нем можно указать переменные `environment`

```
environment:
 - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Debug
 - DbConnection=User ID = postgres; Password = pass; Server = host.docker.internal; Port = 5432; Database = DockerCommands; Integrated Security = true; Pooling = true;
```

AspNetCore удобно конфигурировать именно через `application.json`
Можно конечно переделать и под передачу `environment` переменных

Но что если нужно передать сложный json для конфигурирования?

```
  "MessageBrokerConsumer4InData": {
    "Name": "messageBrokerConsumerBg",
    "AutoStart": false,
    "BatchSize": 1,
    "BrokerEndpoints": "localhost:9092",
    "GroupId": "CommunicationWebService_Consumer",
    "Topics": "CommunicationWebService_InputData"
  }
```

Второй вариант - это создать свой образ на базе моего образа, где будет отредактирован файл `application.json`
Так делают? или это не правильно?

Какие есть возможности настроить приложение в Docker контейнере?
P.S. Контейнер на продакшене будет запускаться в системе оркестрации `Swarm`

Comment: не очень понятно в чём проблема, попробуйте переформулировать вопрос

Comment: Кратко смысл вопроса такой: Если запускать ASp net Core приложение без контейнера, то все настройки можно внести в файл application.json.  Если я создал Image со своей программой и потом создал контейнер на базе этого Image и запсутил его, приложение запустилось и взяло свои настройки  из файла application.json, который также находится в контейнере. Если мне нужно поменять строку подключения к БД, которую раньше я задавал через редактирование application.json, то как быть сейчас? можно как то редактировать application.json в контейнере или задавать параметры из вне?

Comment: навскидку предположу, что нужен скрипт перезаписывающий файл с настройками, может быть даже запускающийся по расписанию. путь к файлу с новыми настройками указать в переменных окружения

Comment: Это значит что  у контейнера должна быть расшарена папка на хост системе, в которой лежат настройки и можно свободно на хост системе менять настройки перед запуском  приложения, чтобы не хардкодить абсолютный путь, этот путь к папке можно передавать через переменные окружения? я правильно понял концепцию? или можно как то внутри контейнера менять настройки?

Comment: примерно как-то так, да

Comment: что-то получилось?

Comment: Сам application.json пока не прокидывал в контейнер, прокинул папку с логами из контейнера на хост. парметризирую запуск через Docker-compose.yml  указывая там все настройки запуска